# Múltiplo UPDATE a partir de um campo dinâmico

Tags: php, array, mysqli, foreach

Estou tentando pegar os `id`s que vem por checkbox selecionados pelo user (array), e através desses `id`s, fazer um update na tabela, com o código a seguir:

```
$ocs_imp = $_POST['check_imprime']; 
$contar = count($ocs_imp);
$id = implode(',',$ocs_imp); 

   $inicio = 0;
   $ultimo = $contar-1;
   $arr = range($inicio, $ultimo);

$sqli = "";
     foreach ( $arr as $k => $v ) {
$sqli .= "UPDATE oc_cadastro SET imprime_oc='s', imprime_oc_data='".$pega_data."' WHERE id = '".$ocs_imp[$v]."')))";
                                  } 

                            $mysqli->query($sqli);
```

Porém não está funcionando, não apresenta erro, simplesmente não atualiza os registros, também tentei com `WHERE id IN ($id)`, sem sucesso.

Comment: Adicione na sua pergunta o erro que você está recebendo que fica mais fácil de te ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado por responder André, não há erro impresso na tela, o procedimento é o sistema pegar os ids e abrir outra página, e ao mesmo tempo fazer o update como no código postado, porém ele abre a outra tela com os ids, mas não faz o update conforme código.

Comment: Removi as saudações e agradecimentos da sua pergunta. Entenda o motivo [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/851/3907).
Removi as tags do título da sua pergunta. Entenda o motivo [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1911/3907).

Comment: Blz @FrancescoPerrotti-Garcia

Comment: Já verificou se o `$_POST['check_imprime']` está retornando  os dados esperados?

Comment: Já sim @luciorubeens, tanto que com os id s recuperados, ele executa outra função que não vem ao caso, e é nessa hora que ele deveria fazer o update e não faz, estou em dúvida se esse código está correto, ou se existe outra maneira.

Comment: Blz, já testou a saída do `$sqli` diretamente no banco?

Comment: O que está em `$mysqli->error` depois de ter executado a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema no código está na concatenação dos SQLs na variável $sqli e executando todos os querys juntos.

Cada query deve ser executada sozinha dessa forma sugiro:

```
foreach ( $arr as $k => $v ) {
    $sqli = "UPDATE oc_cadastro SET imprime_oc='s', imprime_oc_data='".$pega_data."' WHERE id = '".$ocs_imp[$v]."'";
    $mysqli->query($sqli); 
 }
```

Espero te-lo ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Tem alguns parentesses sobre no seu update:

```
"UPDATE oc_cadastro SET 
    imprime_oc='s',
    imprime_oc_data='".$pega_data."'
WHERE id = '".$ocs_imp[$v]."')))";
                             ^^^
--------------------------------
```

Tinha sugerido anteriormente o uso de [multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) que executa várias instruções sql separadas por ponto e vírgula(`;`) porém esse método não parece se adequado para INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE porque ele verifica apenas se a primera instrução está correta e retorna `true` mesmo que as demais possuam erros ou seja ele executa todas instruções até encontrar o primeira errada e para e retorna true como se tudo estiver certo, com isso registros são inseridos/atualizados/removidos pela metade.

Para processar vários INSERTS de uma só vez use multiplos valores na cláusula `VALUES` ex:

```
INSERT INTO tabela (c1, c2, c3) VALUES ('v1', 'v2', 'v3'), ('v12', 'v22', 'v32')
```

No caso do DELETE basta passar os ids na cláusua `IN` ex:

```
DELETE FROM tabela WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

No caso do UPDATE para ter certeza de que todos os registros serão modificados desligue o auto commit, isso significa que o código fonte e não o banco é responsável por efetivar a transação rollback para falha e commit para sucesso. Rode as consulta usando [query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) dentro do foreach.

[Opções - sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
$mysqli->autocommit(false);
$sqli = "";
$erro = false;
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
   $sqli = sprintf("UPDATE oc_cadastro SET
                        imprime_oc = '%s',
                        imprime_oc_data = '%s'
                    WHERE id = %d;", 's', $pega_data, $ocs_imp[$v]);

   if(!$mysqli->query($sql)){
      $erro = true;
      echo 'Atualização cancelada: <br>'. $mysqli->errno .' - '. $mysqli->error;
      break;
  }
}

if($erro == true)
   $mysqli->rollback();
else
   $mysqli->commit();
```

Uma observação:

No trecho da pergunta `$k`(contém os índices do array) não é utlizado em nada, pode então simplificar um pouco o código e removê-la pois `$item` terá o mesmo valor de `$v`.

```
foreach($arr as $item){
   " ... WHERE id = %d;", 's', $pega_data, $ocs_imp[$item]);
```

Comment: Perfeito @rray, como sempre funcionou perfeito. Obrigado mais um vez, não sabia desses comandos rollback e commit, vivendo e aprendendo! Obrigado!

Comment: @DenisL.Murara Isso é chamado de transação em duas fases, alguns bancos deixam por padrão a opção `auto commit` como true outros te obrigam a dar rollback/commit. Ainda falando de transações você pode procurar por alguns assuntos relacionados como, niveis de isolamento, ACID e check save/point que um complemento do rollback/commit.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que o retorno do seu `$_POST['check_imprime']` já é um array:

```
$ocs_imp = $_POST['check_imprime'];
$sql = "";

foreach ($ocs_imp as $id => $val) {
   $sql .= "UPDATE .. WHERE id = {$val};";
}

$mysqli->query($sql);
```